# Are infinite groups "locally topologizable"?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, topological-groups

> Does every infinite group admit a Hausdorff topology such that the  multiplication and inverse are continuous at $1$ but $1$ is not an isolated point?

The question is inspired by and related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/q/173391/24165).

Surely, globally non-topologizable infinite groups [do](https://mathoverflow.net/a/165787/24165) [exist](https://mathoverflow.net/q/114688/24165).

Comment: I don't know, but the class of groups admitting no such topology is closed under taking subgroups, because if $H\subset G$ we can extend the topology on $H$ so that $G\smallsetminus H$ is open and discrete. In particular, a group as in your question will be torsion, and the question boils down to finitely generated groups.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having slept on it, I realise that the answer is **No** (even if we omit the condition on the inverse). The first example of infinite countable non-topologizable group due to Olshanskii (1980) is actually locally non-topologizable.

Indeed, Olshanskii's group $G$ has exponent $p^2$ and the cyclic centre of order $p$. In addition, $g^p\ne1$ for any non-central element of the group. So, if we have a topology on $G$ and the multiplication is continuous at $1$, then the function $f\colon x\mapsto x^p$ is also continuous at $1$. But $f$ takes only finitely many values ($p$ values). Thus, this continuous at $1$ function to a discrete (finite) set must be constant on a neighbourhood of $1$ and, hence, this neighbourhood must be finite (because the $f(x)=1$ only for central $x$).

Details of Olshanskii's construction can be found if [his book](http://books.google.ru/books?id=jwNkqFQn-GcC&lpg=PP1&dq=olshanskii%20geometry%20of%20defining&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: which page‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Comment: I have a Russian edition. This is Chapter 10, Section 31, Subsection 3.

Comment: So this link may be better: http://books.google.com/books?id=jwNkqFQn-GcC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA331#v=onepage&q&f=true btw, I have not found it yet.

Comment: It is on page 339 of English edition. Unfortunately, Google preview rejects to show this page to me (but I may read the table of contents).